# Pandas dataframe read excel then convert to dictinary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, types

I have this code

```
df = pd.read_excel('Simulation log.xlsx', sheet_name='Materials').transpose()
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[1])
df.to_dict()
{'tim': {'density': "{'option': 'constant', 'value': 2300.0}",
'specific_heat': "{'option': 'constant', 'value': 1000.0}",
'thermal_conductivity': "{'option': 'constant', 'value': 2.7}"}}
```

the issue is that I dont want the " " around the dictinary values. I have to pass them along as dictionaries.
I am unsure how and when to to fix it. Is it when I read the excel and create the dataframe or when I have the dictionary. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need convert one column `tim` filled by string repr of dictionaries:

```
import ast

df = pd.read_excel('Simulation log.xlsx', sheet_name='Materials').transpose()
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[1])
```

---

```
df['tim'] = df['tim'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
print (df.to_dict())
{'tim': {'density': {'option': 'constant', 'value': 2300.0},
         'specific_heat': {'option': 'constant', 'value': 1000.0},
         'thermal_conductivity': {'option': 'constant', 'value': 2.7}}}
```

If all columns filled by string repr of dictionaries and need convert them use:

```
df = df.applymap(ast.literal_eval)
print (df.to_dict())
```

If need convert only some columns:

```
cols = ['tim','rob', 'john']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(ast.literal_eval)
print (df.to_dict())
```

Comment: thanks I couldnt fintd the applymap that works on the whole dataframe! Since all are dictinaries then I can use that one. 
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that it reads the data as string from the excel file, you might give this a try (I cannot prove it as I don't have your specific file):

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.read_excel('Simulation log.xlsx', sheet_name='Materials').transpose()
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[1])

# convert string values to dictionaries
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))

# convert df to dict
result_dict = df.to_dict()

print(result_dict)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way.
I thought I could use ast.literal_eval on the whole dataframe that is not possible. So I created the loop.
    for i in df.columns:
        df[i] = df[i].apply(ast.literal_eval)